# Reference for the $\Bbb A^1_k$-rigidity of abelian $k$-varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, abelian-varieties

Is there a reference that shows, for a field $k$, that abelian $k$-varieties are $\Bbb A^1_k$-rigid?

A smooth variety $X$ over $k$ is $\Bbb A^1_k$-rigid if and only if the canonical map
$$
{Hom}_{Var/k}(\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} L,X)\rightarrow {Hom}_{Var/k}(\Bbb A_L^1,X)
$$
is a bijection for every finitely generated separable extension $L/k$, where $\Bbb A_L^1=\Bbb A_k^1\times_{\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}}k} \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}}L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have a reference, but isn't this easy to prove? Any morphism from $\mathbf A^1$ to an abelian variety $X$ is constant. Indeed, such a morphism extends to a morphism $f$ from $\mathbf P^1$ to $X$. For all  global differential forms $\omega$on $X$, the pull-back $f^\star\omega$ is a global differential form on $\mathbf P^1$. Therefore, $f^\star\omega=0$ for all $\omega$. Since the cotangent bundle of $X$ is trivial, this implies that $f$ is constant.

Comment: My background is not in algebraic/differential geometry, so please excuse the naivety of my questions. If I understood it correctly the morphism $\Bbb A^1\rightarrow X$ extends to $\Bbb P^1$ because $X$ is projective, the cotangent bundle of $X$ is trivial because it is an abelian variety, and $f$ is constant because it pulls-back all differential forms of the trivial cotangent bundle to 0, correct?

Comment: I am not sure that the last sentence is completely accurate. What if $f$ is nonconstant but inseparable? (The conclusion is correct, of course.)

Comment: @Nefertiti Oh, yes, I was thinking characteristic zero... Sorry for that!

Comment: @user24453 Yes. For the extension you also use that $\mathbf P^1$ is a smooth curve.

Comment: For reference - here is an argument in arbitrary characteristic: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf proposition 3.9